# XeLaTeX rotating my figures in Beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex

Whenever I compile my beamer presentations with `xelatex`, it forces any .pdf figures I've included with `\includegraphics` to rotate 90 degrees. If I compile with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`, I do not have this problem. Has anyone else seen this issue and/or know how to fix this?

For example, if I compile the following .tex code with `lualtex`, the sizing and positioning of fig1.pdf is as I expect. If I compile with `xelatex`, the figure is rotated by 90 degrees.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{GillSansMT}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fig1.pdf}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Compiling with `xelatex` also outputs the message

```
<use  "fig1.pdf" > [1] (./slides.aux)
** WARNING ** << /Rotate 90 >> found. (Not supported yet)
 )
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that fig1.pdf was created using CERN's ROOT data-analysis software.

Comment: I have a feeling I've seen this before, and that it's to do with the image files. Could you link to a suitable demo image?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't find a ROOT-produced .pdf file to link to at the moment. I'm remembering that ROOT used to create rotated pdfs by default. I guess they threw in the `/Rotate 90` command into the .pdf code as a quick fix, and `xelatex` (and some versions of PowerPoint) doesn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach here is to reprocess the PDF file using GhostScript, which will rewrite it to be 'well behaved':

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=
```

(Linux will have GhostScript installed, Mac users will probably have it as part of MacTeX but Windows users will need to download and install it.)

Answer (score 2):

I did manage to find a work-around for this. If I convert my .pdf image to .ps using `pdf2ps` and then convert it back to .pdf with `ps2pdf`, the figure is properly oriented when compiled with `xelatex`.